# Using Google Map APIs

Tags: rest, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a personal project to develop a REST API which would perform tasks similar to what UBER, OLA like taxi aggregators do. Below is the brief about the functionality that I plan to add:

1)I have a fleet of cabs whose location is determined by its latitude and longitude.

2)A customer can call one of the cabs by providing their location and my API should assign the nearest cab available.

This I suppose would be accomplished by using Google Map APIs. My question is how do i start on using these APIs, to simulate such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following references:

- Choose from the [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) documentations depending on your needs. There are actually tutorials given within the documentations.
- Answers to [Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) will also help especially the [**getting started**](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#getting-started) part to fully understand how Google Maps APIs work.
- Last but definitely not the least, this [example in GitHub](https://github.com/bsvin33t/fuber) might help you exactly on the implementation.